# Exchange issue with log file sector size after RAID firmware upgrade

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

After i upgraded the firmware of my RAID controller i am experiencing issues with my Exchange server.

The Microsoft Exchange Transport Service stops almost immediatly after starting with the following error:

```
IP Filtering Database: An operation has encountered a fatal error. The database may be fragmented and manual offline defragmentation using ESEUTIL may be required. The Microsoft Exchange Transport service is shutting down. Exception details: 
Microsoft.Exchange.Isam.IsamLogSectorSizeMismatchException: the log file sector size does not match the current volume's sector size (-546)    at 
Microsoft.Exchange.Isam.JetInterop.MJetInit(MJET_INSTANCE instance)    at 
Microsoft.Exchange.Isam.Interop.MJetInit(MJET_INSTANCE instance)    at 
Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Storage.DataSource.InitInstance()
```

I tried cleaning all log files and remounting the mailbox database with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Move the database. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125177%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

That will create new files. You can then either remove the old ones and leave them where they are, or move it back. 
Depends if there is content in the queue or not.

Comment: Still having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please also refer to this blog:
[Exchange 2010 Database Availability Groups and Disk Sector Sizes](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2013/04/24/exchange-2010-database-availability-groups-and-disk-sector-sizes/)

It has mentioned that three scenarios could cause the sector size mismatch issue:

◾Storage drivers are upgraded resulting in the recognized sector size changing.

◾Storage firmware is upgraded resulting in the recognized sector size changing.

◾New storage is presented or existing storage is replaced with drives of a different sector size.

Hope it helps,

Best Regards,